# How to render partial template when particular menu clicked in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, yield, iron-router

I am new to Meteor JS. How can I render particular template to particular part of web app,  when menu clicked. I am using iron-router and layout template. 
Following layout is working fine. For example: When user click on 'Home'> 'Article' menu
, I like to render Article template to mainContent region(address bar look like /myapp/Article). Also other menu item works same, when menu item clicked  , particular template displays in mainContent part. How can I route this? I am not sure even it is possible, is there any other way or any better solution around this problem. 
router.js

```
Router.map(function(){this.route('home', {
path: '/',
layoutTemplate: 'homePageLayout',
yieldTemplates: {
  'myHeader': {to: 'header'},
  'mySideMenu': {to: 'sideMenu'},
  'myMainContent': {to: 'mainContent'},
  'myFooter': {to: 'footer'}
}
```

});
});

layout.html

```
<template name="homePageLayout">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {{> yield  region='header'}}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{> yield region='sideMenu'}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {{> yield 'mainContent'}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <footer>
            {{> yield region='footer'}}
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

sideMenu.html

```
<template name="mySideMenu">
<div class="content"></div>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                        Home
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{pathFor 'mission'}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Article
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    News
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Report
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                        Company
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Mission
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    About us
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Contact
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there :)

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    {{> yield 'mainContent'}}
</div>
```

change to

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    {{> yield }}
</div>
```

This is the "main" yield. The iron router will render the template of the route here. To identify the template the IR should render, you can do 2 things.

Do nothing -> Then the Iron Router would render a template named equal to the route's name. In your case it would render the template "home".

Or specify the template for your router:

```
Router.map(function(){
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'mySuperTemplateForThisRoute',
        layoutTemplate: 'homePageLayout',
        yieldTemplates: {
          'myHeader': {to: 'header'},
          'mySideMenu': {to: 'sideMenu'},
          'myMainContent': {to: 'mainContent'},
          'myFooter': {to: 'footer'}
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: <div class="col-lg-6">
    {{> yield }}
</div> I tried to use this, but when particular route is loads, it will display only that template, it is not displaying 'myHeader' and 'myFooter' template. Thats why my layout not works as I draw.

Comment: DerMambo you were right. I missed up my route.configure() I fixed it , now it working fine. Exactly what you said, thank you.I really like to read your blog, keep your hard works thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with my problem like this.
here is my router.js

```
        Router.map(function(){
  this.route('home', {
  path: '/',
  layoutTemplate: 'homePageLayout',
  action: function(){
    this.render('myHeader', {to: 'header'});
    this.render('mySideMenu', {to: 'sideMenu'});
    this.render('home', {to: 'mainContent'});
    this.render('myFooter', {to: 'footer'});
  }
});

  this.route('showMission', {
    path: 'mission',
    layoutTemplate: 'homePageLayout',
    action: function(){
      this.render('myHeader', {to: 'header'});
      this.render('mySideMenu', {to: 'sideMenu'});
      this.render('mission', {to: 'mainContent'});
      this.render('myFooter', {to: 'footer'});
    }
  });

  this.route('showCompanyStructure', {
    path: 'companyStructure',
    layoutTemplate: 'homePageLayout',
    action: function(){
      this.render('myHeader', {to: 'header'});
      this.render('mySideMenu', {to: 'sideMenu'});
      this.render('companyStructure', {to: 'mainContent'});
      this.render('myFooter', {to: 'footer'});
    }
  });

  this.route('showDuties', {
    path: 'duties',
    layoutTemplate: 'homePageLayout',
    action: function(){
      this.render('myHeader', {to: 'header'});
      this.render('mySideMenu', {to: 'sideMenu'});
      this.render('duties', {to: 'mainContent'});
      this.render('myFooter', {to: 'footer'});
    }
  });
});
```

So when particular menu link is clicked it will rendered that template to the 'mainContent' field.
It works fine. But I think there will be more good solution, my solution is repeating code, it may cause 'myheader' and 'myfooter' template loads more than once. I am not sure about it.